# Android Studio unable to Git Push -- I can through terminal

Tags: android, android-studio

I am no longer able to push to github via Android Studio. Everytime I try I now get this error message:

`The operation couldn't be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime. Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java. error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:xxxxxxxxxx'`

Not sure what caused the issue, just started happening one morning (although it was after updating Android Studio to Bumblebee).

I can use the terminal to push just fine, but would really like to get this issue fixed as it's just an easier workflow.

Comment: It's strange that Java isn't found, considering the whole thing runs in Java. Anyways, try going to Settings > Version Control > Git and check `Use credential helper`.

Comment: Well it just randomly started working again -- Not sure if it's because of something I did or if there was an update elsewhere that fixed it. If this occurs to anyone else, try setting the Gradle JDK to a downloaded version rather than using the AS version.

Answer (score 7):

Enable -> Use credential helper

[image: Android Studio Settings]